# How to override query params in PHP's $_SERVER?

Tags: php, xss

I have a URL with a query param like: `www.example.com?src=%27};alert(1);a={%27%27:%27`. I want to clean up the URL when the request gets made and return it to the browser without the javascript alert evaluating. By "clean up" I mean: remove html tags, invalid characters, and characters that can potentially evaluate in the user's browser.

This is what I'm thinking and please correct me if I'm thinking about this incorrectly: when the request is made, catch it in the middleware and then send back a cleaned up version of the query params (maybe redirect the user).

I'm not sure if PHP supports this? I thought I could override the query params in `$_GET` and assign the `src` param with the cleaned up value but that doesn't seem to be working. I've also tried overriding `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` but that also doesn't work.

What's the best way to handle something like this in PHP?

Comment: Firstly, and rather importantly: Do you think you can come up with a reasonable universal definition for "cleaned up"? Cause i've run into too many frameworks that thought they were being helpful when they mangled my form data.

Comment: Good question, I will edit my question. Here, I meant to say something along the lines of stripping tags and characters from the URL that can be interpreted as code.

Comment: There's always `urlencode` and `htmlentities`, if you're worried about the browser interpreting what you're outputting. You ought to be using those anyway, though. :)